# Need to test the complex scenario in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

There's a scenario where I have to first run the 100 POST request and in those request , I will receive the 100 different responses and then using those 100 response value, I need to run the 100 GET request after 5min.of time interval.
Please help me , how to store those 100 different POST responses values and then using those values, need to run GET request.

I tried using JSON extractor as a child of POST request and then the same expression I have used in GET request as well but then it gets overridden. so instead of using 100 different response value, GET request is using only the latest post response value in all the 100 request.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running 100 requests with less than 100 users the previous value will be overwritten by the next value.

I would suggest storing the responses from POST requests (full or partial) into a CSV file using i.e. [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#writer) and use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) or [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) function to parameterize the GET request